# jQuery: Load Script, but as a <pre><code> block?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to load code and display it inside code tags (for syntax highlighting, etc.) like this:

`<pre><code>alert("javascript loaded");</code></pre>`

I am doing this in jQuery right now:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/local/path.js",
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    var code = $("<pre><code>" + data + "</code></pre>");
    $("body").append(code);
  }
})
```

...where `"/local/path.js"` is some code snippet we want to show as part of a blog post but don't want it to execute:

```
# /local/path.js (or /local/path.programming-language-ext)
alert("javascript loaded");
```

The problem is, before `alert("success");` is even called, `alert("javascript loaded");` is called.  That shouldn't be executing, I want to load just a raw string.  That is, I don't want jQuery to do any sort of processing on the response.  How do I do that?  This is all done without any server-side language.

Comment: Please show reference to as where alert("javascript loaded"); is being used if at all?

Comment: That code is just code I want to put as part of say a blog post.  I don't want to execute that code, just display it like I were displaying any other text, like in a README.  The problem is, it's executing.

Comment: you wrote ** `alert("javascript loaded");` is called." ** ....

Comment: so that ajax function loads the string from `"/local/path.programming-language-ext"`, which is that alert.  Somehow, for some reason, jQuery is executing the response... I don't want it to be doing that, but it is.  That's why I say "`alert("javascript loaded");` is called.", jQuery is executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Somehow, for some reason, jQuery is executing the response...

seems weird, have you tried just string in `code` variable?...

```
var code = "<pre><code>" + data + "</code></pre>";
$("body").append(code);
```

---

maybe try adding dataType

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/local/path.js",
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    var code = $("<pre><code>" + data + "</code></pre>");
    $("body").append(code);
  }
})
```

Comment: yeah, it happens before the success function is called, so this is too late.  If I change the file extension name from `.js` to `.something-random`, it works fine.  jQuery must be checking the file extension.  how do i get around that??

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will

> ... intelligently try to get the results,
>   based on the MIME type of the response
>   (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in
>   1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will **execute the
>   script**, and anything else will be
>   returned as a string).

(From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, section `dataType`. Also, see "[Data Types](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types)")

Therefore:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/local/path.js",
  ...
  dataType: 'text'
});
```

---

Alternatively, you should be able to configure your server to send the files in `/local/` as `text/plain` but that's probably *not* the way to go. At least, I prefer to be explicit *in use*, i.e., specify the type where I need it.